integrate $\int\sqrt{\frac{1 - \sqrt{x}}{1 + \sqrt{x}}}dx$
Integrate $\int\sqrt{\frac{1 - \sqrt{x}}{1 + \sqrt{x}}}dx$
This is an elementary integral.I have solved this integral by the method of partial fractions.I want to learn some other elegant method (like some sort of smart variable change) of solving this integral without using the partial fractions.

I would replace the whole thing with a variable: $t=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}}$ :-)
